# display image in JSP using Spring

Tags: java, database, spring, jsp

I'm trying to display an image in jsp injected.
I upload and I store the image in the database, but do not know how retrieve and display in jsp.
My controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ver2", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void ver2(HttpSession session, HttpServletResponse response) {
    OutputStream oImage;
    Item item10 = itemRepository.findOne(11);

    try {
        byte[] photo = item10.getImagen();
        response.setContentType("image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/png, image/gif");
        oImage = response.getOutputStream();
        oImage.write(photo);
        oImage.flush();
        oImage.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

With this code, i show a full screen, and i need inject in jsp. Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return Base64 encoded image bytes in String to your JSP page and use:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,${yourBase64EncodedBytesString}"/>
```

to display your image.

Use [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/) to do Base64 encodings.

So for e.g.:

```
String yourBase64EncodedBytesString = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(content));
```

Set it for e.g. as a request attribute:

```
request.setAttribute("yourBase64EncodedBytesString", yourBase64EncodedBytesString);
```

And retrieve in JSP page:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,${requestScope['yourBase64EncodedBytesString']}"/>
```

Comment: Magnifique, perfect, exact.

thank you very much!!!

I never imagined that I had to encode it first